# Error inserting adaptive card to Compose box from a Message Extension (composeExtension/submitAction) Command

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a message extension, available on the "..." message context menu, that launches a Task Module. In the task module, I submit some sample data (e.g. `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask({"x":"y"});` )

I receive the call for "composeExtension/submitAction", but when I try insert something into the compose box, by submitting a response like the following:

```
            var card = new HeroCard
            {
                Title = "foo",
                Subtitle = "subtitle",
                Text = "bar"
            };

            var attachments = new List<MessagingExtensionAttachment>();
            attachments.Add(new MessagingExtensionAttachment
            {
                Content = card,
                ContentType = HeroCard.ContentType,
                Preview = card.ToAttachment(),
            });

            var activity = new Activity
            {
                Type = ActivityTypesEx.InvokeResponse,
                Value = new InvokeResponse
                {
                    Status = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                    Body = new MessagingExtensionActionResponse
                    {
                        ComposeExtension = new MessagingExtensionResult
                        {
                            AttachmentLayout = "list",
                            Type = "result",
                            Attachments = attachments
                        },
                    }
                }
            };

            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

Then I get an error on the task module, and in the browser debug tools I see the following error:

```
<BotError>Error when processing invoke response: Task or Task Type is missing in Task Module response
```

Here is the payload being returned from my bot to Teams:

```
{
    "task": null,
    "composeExtension": {
        "attachmentLayout": "list",
        "type": "result",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "preview": {
                    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
                    "contentUrl": null,
                    "content": {
                        "title": "foo",
                        "subtitle": null,
                        "text": "bar",
                        "images": null,
                        "buttons": null,
                        "tap": null
                    },
                    "name": null,
                    "thumbnailUrl": null
                },
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
                "contentUrl": null,
                "content": {
                    "title": "foo",
                    "subtitle": null,
                    "text": "bar",
                    "images": null,
                    "buttons": null,
                    "tap": null
                },
                "name": null,
                "thumbnailUrl": null
            }
        ],
        "suggestedActions": null,
        "text": null,
        "activityPreview": null
    }
}
```

The empty "task" object is there because of the "MessagingExtensionActionResponse" type, but I've tried removing it with my own custom type, and I've also tried various ideas of what to possibly put inside there. Per the docs, I can't actually see that a "task" is required though (e.g. per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/messaging-extension-v3/create-extensions?tabs=typescript#compose-extension-result-response)).

Can anybody see where I'm going wrong, or how to guide me to a working solution on this.

[update: minor update to code sample above, as per comments in answer below]

Comment: We tested your code, you are creating an activity instead of that can you please try to return message extension response?Please take a look at [message extension initiate action](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.cs) sample code

Comment: thanks @Nikitha-MSFT, I've looked at that sample, and also at the underlying TeamsActivityHandler at https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Teams/TeamsActivityHandler.cs . From what I can see, I'm basically doing the same thing if you refer to https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Teams/TeamsActivityHandler.cs#L47 and https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/3ee7ebf8b1d4fb150475544656921eb8756c2166/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ActivityHandler.cs#L550 , as far as I can see?

Comment: This is kind of a related question, but is it possible for a message extension to skip the task module entirely, from the message "..." menu (i.e. not send a task/fetch at all) and instead go straight to a "composeExtension/submitAction"?

Comment: Make fetchTask =  false and provide no parameters in the manifest as [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he0Rp.png),then it will  Directly go to composeExtension/submitAction without launching task module. Could you please go through [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/728#issuecomment-505444349)

Comment: I think I actually tried this before, and got the same result... it doesn't work. App Studio shows an error on the "test and dsitribute" screen, and if I -do- try deploy, I get an error popup that says "manifest parsing has failed", with the following log: Error: An error occurred while parsing the manifest.json file; Array item count 0 is less than minimum count of 1. Path 'composeExtensions[0].commands[0].parameters', line 87, position 35.

Comment: So, I managed to side-load it to the tenant store, bypassing app studio. Wen I do, I get the "composeExtension/submitAction" correctly. However, when I send the HeroCard as per above, it doesn't show in the chat, and instead shows a blank task module popup, with an error message "Unable to reach app. Please try again.". The response I'm sending is still the same as in my original post (the Hero Card code is the same too)

Comment: Could you please try [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.cs#L33) code by replacing  card [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.cs#L38) var card = new HeroCard
            {
                Title = "Title here",
                Subtitle = "subtittle",
                Text = "text",
            };

Comment: I'm not fully understanding - basically I'm just adding the "subtitle" property onto the hero card?  If so, I tried it, still no luck

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/51.teams-messaging-extensions-action/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.cs#L33) card has dynamic values, so i asked to replace card values by static values. Could you please try same code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56uQg.png)

Comment: I'm not using dynamic values, I'm also hard-coding, the same as your 2nd link. I've updated my original post with the current code I'm using. My string values are different strings,  but the code is basically the same as your link otherwise. No change in result - still failing

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow- I tried your code snippet and it's [working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LcrN.png) for me. Here is the complete project on [GitHub](https://github.com/Wajeed-msft/MessagingExtensionWithoutTaskModule/blob/master/Bots/TeamsMessagingExtensionsActionBot.cs#L71). Please let me know if you are facing any issues.

Comment: Thanks @Wajeed-MSFT, I appreciate all the effort on this, and your sample eventually helped me figure it out! In my scenario I've got some of my own infrastructure running in order to host in a different hosting environment. I was using the default in-the-box serialization, however, and in the end it was returning a very different payload. See my payload in the original question. In contrast, yours looks much more slimmed down, like this (see next message)

Comment: {
  "composeExtension": {
    "attachmentLayout": "list",
    "type": "result",
    "attachments": [
      {
        "preview": {
          "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
          "content": {
            "title": "foo",
            "subtitle": "subtitle",
            "text": "bar"
          }
        },
        "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.hero",
        "content": {
          "title": "foo",
          "subtitle": "subtitle",
          "text": "bar"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow Could you share an example of how you achieved it? The `microsoftTeams.tasks.submitTask()` call for example?